Laplace equation in 2D with all 0 boundary conditions
I have a pretty basic questions for which I can't find the answer elsewhere. Suppose we have a 2D Laplace equation
$$ \frac{\partial^2 u(x,y)}{\partial x^2}+\frac{\partial^2 u(x,y)}{\partial y^2}=0$$
defined on a rectangle with the boundary conditions:
$$u(0,y)=u(L,y)=u(x,H)=u(x,-H)=0$$
Separation of variables yields:
$$X_n(x)=sin\left(\frac{n\pi x}{L}\right),\;\lambda_n=\left(\frac{n\pi}{L}\right)^2,$$
$$Y_n(y)=-2c_{1} e^{\sqrt{\lambda} y}sinh\left(\frac{n\pi(H-y)}{L}\right).$$
Due to the boundary conditions, is $Y_n(y)=0$ everywhere? Physically, I don't see how this problem is valid, but I'm just curious what happens.

This particular problem has a unique solution.

@Aruralreader Do you have a reference for this unique solution?

See Guenther and Lee’s classic (and classical!) treatment, for instance.

In 2d the elliptic condition always couples locally sinusoidal behaviour with an infinite set of  zeroes to exponentials with one zero at most. So its impossible to construct a zero along the boundary along the fourth side execpt for the 0.function

$\Huge 0$ is the solution !!!.

In this particular case, the exact shape of the boundary is irrelevant because of the maximum principle. And the same result holds for all elliptic operators. So the particular behavior you have noticed is actually related to very powerful/general mathematical tools.
